# Given a list of stabilizers (or parity check matrix), find an encoding circuit

Tags: error-correction, stim, depolarizing-channel

I am trying to study Quantum LDPC code and have generated the A matrix by taking the hypergraph product of a classical LDPC code. Now my aim is to study those matrices by implementing the same on quantum channel.

[image: Taken From the Book]

Comment: Could you define what the "A matrix" is? Maybe give an explicit example you're currently working with?

Comment: Do you mean encoding a random state into a code or encoding the code space (logical zero)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [link(https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.07016#:~:text=We%20show%20that%20belief%20propagation,constructed%20from%20the%20hypergraph%20product.) The paper gives the the construction of Quantum LDPC code and I want this code to be simulated and plot the logical error rate vs prob of error(p). The A matrix is the parity matrix defined as [Hx 0; 0 Hz] [link](https://github.com/shubhamchandak94/stabilizer_code/blob/master/stabilizer_code_report.pdf) here they have given the encoding of A matrix i.e., the stabilizer generator matrix/ parity check matrix.

Comment: @HarshWadhwa Are you referring to the stabilizer tableau represented as a 2nx2n grid of bits? Where did you get the name "A matrix" from?

Comment: This paper is not a circuit-level simulation. It sounds like you want to encode logical 0 though. Simply set every qubit to |0>, measure each stabilizer, correct based on the measurement results, now measure logical Z. If the result is 0, you are properly encoded into logical 0. Otherwise, apply logical X.

Comment: @CraigGidney [link](https://www.elsevier.com/books/quantum-information-processing-quantum-computing-and-quantum-error-correction/djordjevic/978-0-12-821982-9) This book discuss the "A Matrix" in chapter 9.  I have included the image above.

Comment: @esabo : Yes the paper is not about the circuit level simulation. The question which I have in my mind is how to make encoding circuit out of the parity matrix add depolarizing channel say, vary the probability of error and get corresponding the logical error. Is there any tool which can do the said work. Also the paper discuss about the some Belief Propagation decoding which works for Classical LDPC code can that decoding be implemented here at the circuit level too.

Comment: What you are calling the A matrix is called the symplectic form of the stabilizer matrix. The answer to your question is given in Section 8.5.1 in the book. Or, just follow my comments above and plug into Craig's STIM. You will have to program your own decoder though.

Comment: Ah, I see you posted the image above. Note that in my copy, your chapter 9 is my chapter 8. The 9 I have is EAQECCs.

Comment: the codes in the paper are CSS codes and $H_X$ and $H_Z$ are decoded separately as classical codes (using BP + OSD decoder). The paper has a link to bp_osd python decoder which seems to run fine. This is not a circuit level sim as others have commented. I'd say that a circuit level sim for a code this size is not possible with current tools (>100 qubits, non-clifford operations,...)

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you'll want to do is to convert the raw matrix bits into objects Stim understands and can operate efficiently upon. Stim has a method [`stim.PauliString.from_numpy`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/python_api_reference_vDev.md#stim.PauliString.from_numpy) which helps with this conversion:

```
import stim
import numpy as np
from typing import List


def parity_check_matrix_to_stabilizers(matrix: np.ndarray) -> List[stim.PauliString]:
    num_rows, num_cols = matrix.shape
    assert num_cols % 2 == 0
    num_qubits = num_cols // 2

    matrix = matrix.astype(np.bool8)  # indicate the data isn't bit packed
    return [
        stim.PauliString.from_numpy(
            xs=matrix[row, :num_qubits],
            zs=matrix[row, num_qubits:],
        )
        for row in range(num_rows)
    ]
```

You can expand the partial list of stabilizers into a tableau, with a full list of stabilizer generators alongside destabilizer generators, by using [`stim.Tableau.from_stabilizers`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/python_api_reference_vDev.md#stim.Tableau.from_stabilizers). Then the last piece of the puzzle is [`stim.Tableau.to_circuit`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/python_api_reference_vDev.md#stim.Tableau.to_circuit). This will produce a working (but not efficient or internally fault tolerant) encoding circuit:

```
def parity_check_matrix_to_encoder(matrix: np.ndarray) -> stim.Circuit:
    stabilizers = parity_check_matrix_to_stabilizers(matrix)
    tableau = stim.Tableau.from_stabilizers(
        stabilizers,
        allow_underconstrained=True,
    )
    return tableau.to_circuit(method='elimination')
```

Trying it out:

```
surface_code_2x2_encoder = parity_check_matrix_to_encoder(np.array([
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
]))
print(surface_code_2x2_encoder.diagram())
# prints:
# q0: -H-@-@---
#        | |
# q1: ---X-|---
#          |
# q2: -----|-X-
#          | |
# q3: -----X-@-
```

Comment: I used something similar based on your answer here https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/27326/how-to-go-from-matrix-to-tableau-to-circuit-in-qiskit-or-stim When's the next release of stim? I'm not used to working with dev versions

Comment: @unknown There's not really any schedule to them I just package them up now and then when I feel like there's enough to describe.